# Difference between Google Sign-In vs PassportJS GoogleStrategy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-signin

What are the advantages/disadvantages or differences between the Google Sign-In implementation here `https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in` versus PassportJS `passport-google-oauth20`? Or am I misunderstanding and they are basically the same thing?

I am currently using PassportJS `LocalStrategy` but would like to re-implement user authentication using Google.

Comment: I have the same question. Would you like to answer it now?

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is I just chose to use Google Sign in